# How to convert string to struct array

Tags: go, unmarshalling

I have a json array which is converted into a string. Now I want to map the string to a struct array so that I can modify the string json. Below is my code base

```golang
type ProcessdetailsEntity struct {
    Source   []int64 `json:"source"`
    Node     string  `json:"node"`
    Targets  []int64 `json:"targets"`
    Issave   bool    `json:"isSave"`
    Instate  []int64 `json:"inState"`
    OutState []int64 `json:"outState"`
}

func main() {
    var stringJson = "[{\"source\":[-1],\"node\":\"1_1628008588902\",\"targets\":[],\"isSave\":true,\"inState\":[1],\"outState\":[2]},{\"source\":[\"1_1628008588902\",\"5_1628008613446\"],\"node\":\"2_1628008595757\",\"targets\":[],\"isSave\":true,\"inState\":[2,5],\"outState\":[3,6]}]"
    in := []byte(stringJson)
    detailsEntity := []ProcessdetailsEntity{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(in, &detailsEntity)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
    }
}
```

Now when I run this code base I got the error:

```
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field ProcessdetailsEntity.source of type int64
```

How to properly map the string to struct so that I can modify the `inState` and `outState` value of the json ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get is already pretty much on the nose:

> cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field ProcessdetailsEntity.source of type int64

That tells you that (at least one) of your `source` fields appears to have the wrong type: a `string` instead of something that can be represented by a `int64`.

So let's check your `source` fields in your `stringJson`:

```json
"source":[-1]
"source":["1_1628008588902","5_1628008613446"]
```

As you can see the second `source` is an array of `string`. Hence the error.

To solve this you need to make sure that the `source` is an array of `int`. Unfortunately, `1_1628008588902` and `5_1628008613446` are not valid integers in Go.

I slightly modified your JSON and fixed your code an then it works:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
)

type ProcessdetailsEntity struct {
    Source   []int64 `json:"source"`
    Node     string  `json:"node"`
    Targets  []int64 `json:"targets"`
    Issave   bool    `json:"isSave"`
    Instate  []int64 `json:"inState"`
    OutState []int64 `json:"outState"`
}

func main() {
    var stringJson = `[
        {
            "source":[-1],
            "node":"1_1628008588902",
            "targets":[],
            "isSave":true,
            "inState":[1],
            "outState":[2]
        },
        {
            "source":[11628008588902,51628008613446],
            "node":"2_1628008595757",
            "targets":[],
            "isSave":true,
            "inState":[2,5],
            "outState":[3,6]
        }
    ]`
    
    in := []byte(stringJson)
    detailsEntity := []ProcessdetailsEntity{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(in, &detailsEntity)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
    }
}
```

See: https://play.golang.org/p/kcrkfRliWJ5